# Confusion in understanding new initial terms of Tor sequence

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

Cartan and Eilenberg mention in their book on Homological Algebra the following:

Consider exact sequence of right $\Lambda$-modules
$$(1)\hskip1cm 0\rightarrow A'\rightarrow A\rightarrow A''\rightarrow 0.$$

Tensor this sequence with a left $\Lambda$-module, the following portion is always exact:
$$
(2)\hskip2cm A'\otimes_{\Lambda} C \rightarrow A\otimes_{\Lambda} C \rightarrow A''\otimes_{\Lambda} C \rightarrow 0.
$$
... The kernel $K$ of the homomorphism on the left in the sequence $(2)$ is in general not zero.

In case $A$ is free module, it can be shown that (up to natural isomorphism) $K$ depends only on $A''$ and $C$.

We define the torsion product $\mbox{Tor}^{\Lambda}_1(A'',C)$ to be kernel in this case.

($\star$) In the general case there is a natural homomorphism $
\mbox{Tor}^{\Lambda}_1(A'',C)\rightarrow A'\otimes_{\Lambda} C
$ with image $K$.

Continuing in this way we obtain an infinite exact sequence
$$
(3)\hskip1cm \mbox{Tor}^{\Lambda}_{n+1}(A'',C)\rightarrow 
\mbox{Tor}^{\Lambda}_n(A',C)\rightarrow  
\mbox{Tor}^{\Lambda}_n(A,C)\rightarrow 
\mbox{Tor}^{\Lambda}_n(A'',C)\rightarrow \cdots$$
**Question 1.** If $\mbox{Tor}^{\Lambda}_1(A'',C)$ is defined as kernel of left map in $(2)$, then  the natural inclusion is natural homomorphism; what is the importance of assertion $(\star)$?

**Question 2.** The starting sequence was **short** exact sequence $(1)$, and tensoring it with $C$ we get partially exact sequence $(2)$; the kernel of left map in $(2)$ gives a new term of long exact sequence $\mbox{Tor}_{1}^{\Lambda}(A'',C)$; how the next term $\mbox{Tor}_{1}^{\Lambda}(A,C)$ is obtained? (I want to understand the initial/beginning steps of the long exact sequence.)

Comment: "In case A is free module, [...]" - i.e. In general, $\mbox{Tor}^{\Lambda}_1(A'',C)$ is not necessarily $K$.  I don't currently know if this answers your questions, but you seem to be assuming $\mbox{Tor}^{\Lambda}_1(A'',C) = K$ in your questions.

Comment: Iirc, you'd need to consider a free resolution of $A''$ and break it into short exact sequences using its syzygies to use this as your definition of Tor.  Otherwise it's just a special case.

Comment: @Brian: [(.. the kernel $K$ of the homomorphism on left ... ) .... (...we define torsion product $\mbox{Tor}^{\Lambda}_1(A'',C)$  to be kernel in this case ...) .... ] doesn't this say that $K$ is equal to $\mbox{Tor}^{\Lambda}_1(A'',C)$?

Comment: @Brian: I got little clarification from your first two lines; thanks for this clarification.

Comment: @MathsRahul You are overlooking the phrase "**in this case**". When things are free, definitions are simple. They get complicated for arbitrary modules that are not free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For question 1, I believe that the assertion $(*)$ is important only in the general case when A is not necessarily free and $Tor_1^{\Lambda}(A'',C)$ is not necessarily $K$. The assertion is essentially saying that you have this part of the long exact sequence:
$$Tor_1^{\Lambda}(A'',C) \rightarrow A'\otimes C \rightarrow A\otimes C 
$$

But, well, yes, it isn't much relevant if you are only assuming that $Tor_1^{\Lambda}(A'',C)=K$.